# How can I get memory and CPU usage of an external process with Java?

Tags: java, monitoring, memory-management, cpu-usage

I need to get info for memory and CPU usage of some process running on the machine (not the Java process).

How can I do that?

Comment: Is the other process a java application?

Comment: Why you closed it? it not a duplicate of the the other thread!!! I was talking about receiving info of other specific process - it is not the subject of the other tread

Comment: Indeed, the other Question is about the *computer*'s system usage while OP is looking for information about a specific *proecess*. I have voted for reopening.

Answer (score 2):

It's platform dependent, but essentially use `Runtime.getRuntime()` to execute the appropriate command, capture its output and parse it for the data you need.

Comment: @home - Thanks, `Australia` has really cute animals:)

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken `Runtime.getRuntime` is for the virtual machine and not the physical. What you are about asking is getting the physical machine information (meaning the CPU).