# Java - How can i monitor Memory and CPU usage of other process

Tags: java

I need to get info for memory and CPU usage of some process running on the machine (not the Java process).

How can I do that?

[I reopened the thread after it was closed as a duplicate of other thread. The other thread is not relevant, it is not talking about receiving information of other specific process].

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java - how can I get memory and CPU usage of a process?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7377271/java-how-can-i-get-memory-and-cpu-usage-of-a-process)

Comment: Of couse it is a duplicate of this one! i opened both of them. I reopened the thread because the first one was closed although it should not have been closed

Comment: You should edit the closed one, not post a new question.

Answer (score 1):

Following are the choices for different platforms

1. [Sigar](http://support.hyperic.com/display/SIGAR/Home)
2. [JavaSysMon](https://github.com/jezhumble/javasysmon)
3. [Oshi](http://oshi.codeplex.com/)

Another possible way could be to call Native application for Monitoring from java using **ProcessBuilder**
or **RunTime** java classes